# Xcode 4.6 / 5 with lldb breakpoints not working

Tags: xcode, breakpoints

I had a problem with using debugger LLDB,

if in "main.c" , I include another file like "a.c" , and set breakpoint in "a.c"
the breakpoint will never been stopped.

Is anyone else getting this?

ok, here is the example

```
// main.c
#include "a.c"
int main()
{
    test();
}


// a.c
void test()
{
    return; // (Using UI to)set break point here, the gdb will stop, and lldb will not
}
```

======================================================================

To trojanfoe:
I had tried these steps in Xcode 4.6.3 command line utilities,
the result is like yours, but my problem is on GUI,

When I use the mouse to set a break point on "a.c", it will not work.

I had tried to stop on main(), and enter this cmd "br list",
here is the message on console,

```
(lldb) br list
Current breakpoints:
1: file ='a.c', line = 13, locations = 0 (pending)


2: file ='main.c', line = 15, locations = 1, resolved = 1

  2.1: where = test`main + 15 at main.c:15, address = 0x0000000100000f3f, resolved, hit count = 1 

(lldb)
```

if you need the log by using command line utilities, please tell me,
thanks~

Comment: Sorry not sure I understand. Please can you provide more information.

Comment: Is anything in `a.c` being called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See "File and line breakpoints are not getting hit" in http://lldb.llvm.org/troubleshooting.html - that seems to be talking about exactly your build scenario, and I've just had this problem. To solve it I not only had to put this in $HOME/.lldbinit:

settings set target.inline-breakpoint-strategy always

I also had to do a clobber (distclean) build and restart Xcode.

Comment: This was exactly my problem: Breakpoints in .cpp files that were #included from a central .cpp were being ignored. Adding the line, restarting Xcode and clean building did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE** This is not an answer, however I wanted to document the *works for me* response fully.

OP: Please follow these steps to see how it differs for you.

```
$ clang -g -o bptest main.c
$ ls -l
total 32
-rw-r--r--  1 andy  staff   110 Oct 31 10:55 a.c
-rwxr-xr-x  1 andy  staff  4664 Oct 31 10:56 bptest
drwxr-xr-x  3 andy  staff   102 Oct 31 10:56 bptest.dSYM     (NOTE THIS)
-rw-r--r--  1 andy  staff    42 Oct 31 10:55 main.c
$ lldb
(lldb) target create bptest
Current executable set to 'bptest' (x86_64).
(lldb) break set -b test
Breakpoint 1: where = bptest`test + 4 at a.c:4, address = 0x0000000100000f34
(lldb) run
Process 9743 launched: '/Users/andy/tmp/bptest/bptest' (x86_64)
Process 9743 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x65287, 0x0000000100000f34 bptest`test + 4 at a.c:4, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread, stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000100000f34 bptest`test + 4 at a.c:4
   1    // a.c
   2    void test()
   3    {
-> 4        return; // (Using UI to)set break point here, the gdb will stop, and lldb will not
   5    }
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x65287, 0x0000000100000f34 bptest`test + 4 at a.c:4, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread, stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000100000f34 bptest`test + 4 at a.c:4
    frame #1: 0x0000000100000f49 bptest`main + 9 at main.c:4
    frame #2: 0x00007fff8eb3f7e1 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
(lldb)
```

Note: I am using the Xcode 5.0.1 command line utilities.